# Closed form of the following Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $L\colon\mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ satisfy the following recurrence relationship,

$$
L(a,b,c) = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \sum_{j=0}^{b-1} \sum_{k=0}^{c-1} L(i,j,k),
$$

With "initial conditions" $L(0,a,b) = L(c,0,d) = L(0,e,f) = 0$.  I am interested in knowing a closed form of $L$.

Work I have done:

I have investigated a simpler case
$
G\colon \mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{N}
$, satisfying 
$$G(a,b) = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} \sum_{j=0}^{b-1} G(i,j)$$
with similar "initial conditions" and can obtain $$G(a,b) = \binom{a+b-2}{a-1}= \binom{a+b-2}{b-1}= \frac{(a-b-2)!}{(a-1)!(b-1)!},$$ so I would have guessed that $$L(a,b,c) = \frac{(a+b+c-3)!}{(a-1)!(b-1)!(c-1)!}, $$ but this isn't correct.  I would appreciate any hints on how to find a closed form solution for this.

Comment: A natural approach is to compute the generating function $$F(x,y,z)=\sum_{a,b,c\geqslant1}L(a,b,c)x^ay^bz^c$$ and to identify each $L(a,b,c)$ as the coefficient of the monomial $x^ay^bz^c$ in the result. In the two dimensional case, one would consider $$H(x,y)=\sum_{a,b\geqslant1}G(a,b)x^ay^b$$ and the recursion you indicate yields $$H(x,y)=\frac{x}{1-x}\frac{y}{1-y}+\frac{x}{1-x}\frac{y}{1-y}H(x,y)$$ hence $$H(x,y)=\frac{xy}{1-x-y}=xy\sum_{n\geqslant0}(x+y)^n=xy\sum_{n\geqslant0}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^ky^{n-k}$$ that is, $$H(x,y)=xy\sum_{i,j\geqslant0}\frac{(i+j)!}{i!j!}x^iy^j$$  from ...

Comment: ... which one can deduce the formula you give for each $G(a,b)$. Did you try this for the coefficients $L(a,b,c)$?

Comment: To be honest, I just had vague feelings that the binomial coefficients were involved and I looked at the values.  It wasn't too hard to get my result.  I like your approach.

Comment: @Did please expand this into an answer. This is enough to stand as an answer with the prefix **Hint:**

Comment: It is Probably worth noting that $F(x,y,z) = \frac{x y z}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)} \left(1 - \frac{x y z}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)} \right)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x y z}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)} \right)^i$.

Comment: @fred Another route is $$F(x,y,z)=\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)-xyz}=xyz\sum_{n\geqslant0}(x+y+z-xy-yz-zx+2xyz)^n$$ but I fail to see at present how to expand neatly this series (or the one in your comment).

Comment: @Did What about writing $F(x,y,z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i\bigg)^n \bigg( \sum_{j=1}^\infty y^j \bigg)^n \bigg( \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k\bigg)^n$?  My guess is you already considered this?

Comment: @fred very clever deduction (re. your first formula for $ F(x,y,z)$) ! It is definitely worth to be posted and voted !

Comment: @fred Yes I did, and I see only unsatisfying sums at the end of this route... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing according to Fred's very clever deduction of the multiple z-tranform
 ( the credit should go to him, so I invite him to post it, and votes to be casted on it as well)
$$
F(x,y,z) = \frac{{\frac{{x\,y\,z}}
{{\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {1 - y} \right)\left( {1 - z} \right)}}}}
{{1 - \frac{{x\,y\,z}}
{{\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {1 - y} \right)\left( {1 - z} \right)}}}} = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( {\frac{{x\,y\,z}}
{{\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {1 - y} \right)\left( {1 - z} \right)}}} \right)^{\,n} } 
$$
and considering that
$$
\frac{{z^n }}
{{\left( {1 - z} \right)^n }} = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n - 1 + k \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\,\,z^{\,n + k} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  j - 1 \\ 
  j - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\,\,z^{\,j} } 
$$
then we have
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( {\frac{{x\,y\,z}}
{{\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {1 - y} \right)\left( {1 - z} \right)}}} \right)^n }  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,a,\;b,\;c\;} {\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b,c} \right)} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  a - 1 \\ 
  a - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  b - 1 \\ 
  b - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  c - 1 \\ 
  c - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} } \right)x^{\,a} \,y^{\,b} \,z^{\,c} }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
i.e.
$$
\begin{gathered}
  L(a,b,c) = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b,c} \right)} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  a - 1 \\ 
  a - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  b - 1 \\ 
  b - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  c - 1 \\ 
  c - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b,c} \right)} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  a - 1 \\ 
  n - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  b - 1 \\ 
  n - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  c - 1 \\ 
  n - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Note that:

- in 1D it becomes $L(a,b,c) = 2^{\,a - 1} $
- in 2D
  $$
  \begin{gathered}
    L(a,b) = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b} \right)} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
    a - 1 \\ 
    a - n \\ 
  \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
    b - 1 \\ 
    b - n \\ 
  \end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
     = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b} \right)} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
    a - 1 \\ 
    n - 1 \\ 
  \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
    b - 1 \\ 
    b - n \\ 
  \end{gathered}  \right)}  = \left( \begin{gathered}
    a + b - 2 \\ 
    b - 1 \\ 
  \end{gathered}  \right) \hfill \\ 
  \end{gathered} 
  $$
- but in 3D I do not know if there is a closed form.

  ---

*Addendum*
Again thanks to Fred's hint, actually $L(a,b,c)$ can also be expressed in terms of Hypergeometric Function, as
$$
\begin{gathered}
  L(a,b,c) = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b,c} \right)} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  a - 1 \\ 
  a - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  b - 1 \\ 
  b - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  c - 1 \\ 
  c - n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b,c} \right) - 1} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  a - 1 \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  b - 1 \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  c - 1 \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b,c} \right) - 1} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \left( \begin{gathered}
  n - a \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \left( \begin{gathered}
  n - b \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \left( \begin{gathered}
  n - c \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,n\,\left( { \leqslant \,\min \left( {a,b,c} \right) - 1} \right)} {\frac{{\left( {1 - a} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } \left( {1 - b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } \left( {1 - c} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }}
{{1^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } \;1^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }}\frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} }}
{{n!}}}  =  \hfill \\
   = {}_3F_{\,2} \left( {\left( {1 - a} \right),\left( {1 - b} \right),\left( {1 - c} \right);\;\;1,1;\;\; - 1} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
although, having the variable $z$ fixed at $-1$, we are not much exploiting that function.

Comment: I gave the formula you supplied to Mathematica and it says that $L(a,b,c) = \mathrm{HypergeometricPFQ}[\{1-a,1-b,1-c\},\{1,1\},-1]$  ... whatever that means. :).

Comment: @fred, oh yes, hypergeometric f. might well be a way to write it ! that's interesting. But I see you did not post your $F(x,y,z)$, why?

Comment: I think that you and @Did did almost all the work.  I am happy to let you both have any upvotes.  Thank you.

Comment: The hypergeometric function formula does not bring much since it basically put a name on the series, in this sense there is no really satisfying solution to the 3D case, apparently. Apart from that, this answer summarizes what is on the page.

Comment: yes in fact. I take the chance to thank you for the contribution as @fred pointed, and for the appreciation of the summarizing.