# Determine Coefficient from Generating Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let $G\colon \mathbb{N}^3\to \mathbb{N}$ be such that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i \bigg)^n \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^\infty y^j \bigg)^n\bigg( \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k\bigg)^n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty G(i,j,k) x^i y^j z^k.
$$

How can I find a closed form for $G$?  This question is related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913600/closed-form-of-the-following-recurrence-relation).  I am not well versed with generating functions.  Any hints are well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first we derive a closed form of the generating function $\mathcal{G}(x,y,z)$ and then we extract the coefficient $G(i,j,k)$ from it.

> **Generating function:** $\mathcal{G}(x,y,z)$
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{G}(x,y,z)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^i \right)^n
> \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty y^j\right)^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k\right)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^n\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\left(1-\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\right)^{-1}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

We apply in (1) and (2) the formula for the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.

> **Coefficient extraction:** $G(i,j,k)$
>
> We denote with $[x^i]$ the coefficient of $x^i$ in a series. This way we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> G(i,j,k)&=[x^iy^jz^k]\mathcal{G}(x,y,z)\\
> &=[x^i][y^j][z^k]\mathcal{G}(x,y,z)
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> G(i,j,k)&=[x^iy^jz^k]\mathcal{G}(x,y,z)\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty[x^i]\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n[y^j]\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^n[z^k]\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^n\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> We have three similar parts and put the focus on the first one.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^i]\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n&=[x^i]x^n\sum_{p=0}^\infty\binom{-n}{p}(-x)^p\tag{4}\\
> &=[x^{i-n}]\sum_{p=0}^\infty\binom{n+p-1}{p}x^p\tag{5}\\
> &=\begin{cases}
> \binom{i-1}{i-n}\qquad&\qquad 1\leq n\leq i\\
> 0\qquad&\qquad\text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
- In (5) we use the rule $[x^{i-n}]A(x)=[x^i]x^nA(x)$. Note that $[x^{i-n}]$ is zero if $i<n$. We also use the binomial identity $\binom{-n}{p}=\binom{n+p-1}{p}(-1)^p$.

> Putting all together in (3) we finally obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> G(i,j,k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\min\{i,j,k\}}\binom{i-1}{i-n}\binom{j-1}{j-n}\binom{k-1}{k-n}\qquad\qquad 1\leq n\leq i,j,k
> \end{align*}